What criteria did Christ not meet to be the messiah?
The Jewish faith obviously rejects Christ as the upcoming messiah, but I was wondering why don't you believe that Christ was the sent messiah and what criteria did Christ not meet in order to be considered the messiah? (I ask this question with respect and love)

Literally all of them. He accomplished nothing except some nonsensical inventions put forth by the Gospels, like riding a donkey (well who the heck hadn't ridden on a donkey). Christianity is built around a series of lies, mistranslations, and verses taken out of context. As I like to say: "Christian, Hebrew Bible scholar, intellectually honest: pick two." At the end of the day, how many proof-texts can be demonstrably false before you start to question whether your "holy" book is in fact holy after all? I say one. But for many Christians, that number appears to be over 300....

If you want to know in great detail why Jews reject Jesus, watch some videos of Rabbi Tovia Singer.

The biggest fail pertains to the explicit teaching directly from G-d (who you would call "the Father") in Deuteronomy 4:2 and 13:1 which says not to add to G-d's laws as they have been given to you including what is taught in the Oral Torah. In chapter 13, it says that there will be in the future, one from among the Jews, sent by G-d, to test Israel about this, whether they love G-d (the Father), that they will not depart from G-d's laws. Jesus added to G-d's commandments like is recorded in John 15:1-17. Jesus says the commandment he adds is to see whether you love him instead.

If Joseph if not his father then he is not a male line descendent of King David.
He didn't restore the Davidic Kingdom or gather in the exiles or usher in a era of world peace. Xtians say he will do this at his "second coming" but there is no mention of a second coming in any of the messianic prophecies in the Torah or Neviim.

@DavefromBaltimore The monarchy from the House of King David is not so straightforward. If an unmarried Jewish woman has relations with a gentile and bears a child, that child is associated to her father, its grandfather, in terms of lineage according to some opinions. Regarding the subject of "2nd coming", if you mean resurrection, that is also not so straightforward. There are definite traditional, Orthodox teachings that leave that possibility open. See, for example, Sukkah 52b and the resurrection of the 7 Shepherds and 8 Anointed Individuals.

@eliezer I'm not here to be an apologist for Christianity. But what you are expressing is not the majority viewpoint among Christians today. If you were looking for a common nomenclature within traditional Jewish belief and teaching, it is the distinction between G-d and his names. We say in prayer, "Blessed is He and blessed is His name." That G-d and His name is one, like is emphasized in the Aleinu prayer. He transcends all letters and all His names. And yet, He and His name are one.

@eliezer Shavuah tov. Your issue is about the explicit teaching of Yehoshuah ben Nun, the prophet who replaced Moshe Rabbeinu and brought the Jewish people into the land of Israel. He is the one who, according to Jewish tradition, authored the Aleinu prayer which teaches all of us that G-d (הוא) and His name(s) (ושמו) are one. My suggestion would be to go and review carefully the text of that prayer which all Jews say at the conclusion of each daily prayer, three times each day (שחרית, מנחה וערבית), which is Roshei Teivot שמ״ע, as in: שמע ישראל הוי׳ אלקינו הוי׳ אחד.

@eliezer Your lack of punctuation, run-on sentences and poor grammar make it extremely difficult to understand anything you are trying to express. I have no relationship to Christianity. My first comment was directed to the OP only, who appears to be Christian. I used the expression “the Father” to give him understanding from “his nomenclature” where the source and authority of Jewish law comes from. I am quite familiar with Zechariah, who repeated the earlier teaching.  The later prophets do not bring innovations, only restatements. It doesn’t change what I wrote.

@eliezer It is referring to how our perception will change. Currently, our perception of reality is distorted. But reality itself is unchanging and eternal. The concept of true reality (in English) is G-d. In books that discuss this type of subject, this is often referred to by the Hebrew expression אמת באמתתו. See for example, Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, 1:4.
